# QuerySnapshot.empty causes a promise rejection error

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, ecmascript-5, firebase-admin

I have a back-end using firebase-admin and express to allow post requests from the client to the server to make changes to the firestore I have that contains stuff like user data (this is a test and not a real product). I want to check if a document already exists so a user cannot register with that username again. I have first seen instances of doc.exists but that returns undefined for me and I looked into the documentation and found doc.empty which is said to check if a document is empty. I tried it but it returned a promise rejection error. If I changed that line to .exists or to something else, that goes away so I have narrowed down the issue to that line.

index.js (backend)

```js
app.post("/registeruser", function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    try {
        const username = req.body.username;
        const password = req.body.password;
        const passwordEncrypted = HmacSHA1(password, JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./keys.json"))["passwordEncryptKey"]).toString();

        // console.log(username, password, passwordEncrypted);

        try {
            firestore.collection("users").get(username).then(function (data) {
                if (data.empty == false) {
                    throw [true, "Already registered user!"];
                }
            }).catch(function (error) {
                throw [true, error];
            });

            if (username == "") {
                firestore.collection("users").add({
                    username: v4(),
                    passwordhash: passwordEncrypted,
                    email: "example@gmail.com",
                }).then(function () {
                    return res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({
                        error: false,
                        message: "Successfully registered user!",
                    }))
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    throw [true, error];
                });
            }
            else {
                firestore.collection("users").doc(username).set({
                    username: username,
                    passwordhash: passwordEncrypted,
                    email: "example@gmail.com",
                }).then(function () {
                    return res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({
                        error: false,
                        message: "Successfully registered user!",
                    }));
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    throw [true, error];
                });
            }
        }
        catch (error) {
            throw [true, error];
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        const [isError, errorMessage] = error;

        return res.status(404).send(JSON.stringify({
            error: isError,
            message: errorMessage,
        }));
    }
});
```

Terminal Output

> (node:29448) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: [object Array]
> (node:29448) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
> (node:29448) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple concurrent promise chains, and some of those can fail independently. You need to consolidate all your logic into one promise chain.

```
return firestore.collection("users").get(username)
  .then((data) => {
    if (data.empty == false) {
      throw [true, "Already registered user!"];
    }
  })
  .then(() => {
    if (username == '') {
      return firestore.collection("users").add({/* Your data */});
    }

    return firestore.collection("users").doc(username).set({/* Your data */});
  })
  .then(() => {
    return res.status(200);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    return res.status(500);
  });
```

You can also try using async/await which will significantly simplify logic like this.